# How to get value of particular name in xml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby-on-rails-4, xml-parsing, ruby-on-rails-5.1

```
        <ecomexpress-objects version="1.0">
        <object pk="1" model="awb">
        <field type="BigIntegerField" name="awb_number">700054480</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="orderid">5012</field>
        <field type="FloatField" name="actual_weight">0.5</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="origin">DELHI-DSW</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="destination">DELHI-DLN</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="customer">Ecom Express Private Limited - 32012</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="consignee">MUKESH KUMAR GUPTA</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="pickupdate">11-Feb-2013</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="status">Delivered / Closed</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="reason_code"/>
        <field type="CharField" name="reason_code_description"/>
        <field type="CharField" name="reason_code_number">999</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="receiver">mukesh 9999488339</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="expected_date">12-Feb-2013</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="last_update_date">05-Apr-2013</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="delivery_date">2013-02-17 11:26:00</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="ref_awb">None</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="rts_shipment"/>
        <field type="CharField" name="system_delivery_update">2013-02-17 11:26:00 </field>
        <field type="CharField" name="rts_system_delivery_status"/>
        <field name="scans">
        <object pk="1" model="scan_stages">
        <field type="DateTimeField" name="updated_on">05 Apr, 2013, 19:40 hrs</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="status">SAL Tally closed</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="reason_code"/>
        <field type="CharField" name="reason_code_number"/>
        <field type="CharField" name="location">DLN</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="Employee">Umesh Jaswanti - 10015</field>
        </object>
        <object pk="2" model="scan_stages">
        <field type="DateTimeField" name="updated_on">05 Apr, 2013, 19:39 hrs</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="status">SAL Tally closed</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="reason_code"/>
        <field type="CharField" name="reason_code_number"/>
        <field type="CharField" name="location">DLN</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="Employee">Umesh Jaswanti - 10015</field>
        </object>
        </field>
        </object>
        </ecomexpress-objects>
```

i know the simple file xml file like

```
 <HEUREKA>
  <CATEGORY>
    <CATEGORY_ID>971</CATEGORY_ID>
    <CATEGORY_NAME>Auto-moto</CATEGORY_NAME>
  </CATEGORY>
  <CATEGORY>
   <CATEGORY_ID>881</CATEGORY_ID>
   <CATEGORY_NAME>Alkohol testery</CATEGORY_NAME>
   <CATEGORY_FULLNAME>Heureka.cz | Auto-moto | Alkohol testery</CATEGORY_FULLNAME>
   </CATEGORY>
</HEUREKA>
```

how to read itand get particular value but in first case i want to get ***status = 'Delivered / Closed'***
how can i get it..

of it is there any tutorial to read the file any get the value then please share with me

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/) gem.

Comment: You can parse xml file with Nokogiri:
`doc = File.open("file.xml") { |f| Nokogiri::XML(f) }`
Nokogiri will return an data object and you can work with it.